# Reset and clear Gnome Terminal not working

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome-terminal

I'm using GNOME Terminal 2.31.3.

I was at work, ssh'ed into a machine at work.  I came home and obviously broke the connection, so I want to reset that terminal tab.

There is a menu option **Terminal > Reset and Clear**.  This menu option will clear the terminal window, but it does not appear to reset.  I can't type anything in that tab.  I have to close the tab and open another one.

EDIT: Haha.  Funny.  I cruised around stack overflow for a while, and now when I come back to my terminal, it says `Write failed: Broken pipe` and finally I can type again.

Is this a bug?  Shouldn't reset give me a clean terminal session/shell that I can start using right away?

Comment: Reset is like closing the terminal window and opening a new one. I'm not sure what's the difference between Reset and Reset and Clear, though. If you just want to clear the terminal screen (and not just add blank spaces like `clear` does), you can use just `reset`.

Comment: Thanks @Alex.  I edited the question to be more specific.